# Given a number N how many pairs of numbers have square sum less than or equal to N?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Let's define $F(N)$ as the number of pairs of distinct positive integers $(A, B)$ such that $A^2 + B^2 \leq N$

If $N=5$ the only possible such pair is $(1, 2)$, for $N=10$ the pairs are two: $(1,2)$ and $(1,3)$.

Then we have $F(13)=3$, $F(17)=4$, $F(20)=5$, $F(25)=6$ and so on for every number which is sum of two distinct non-zero squares.

**Is there any closed-form formula to calculate $F(N)$?**

Answer (score 2):

The point $(A, B)$ fits within a circle of radius $\sqrt{N}$.
There are about $\pi N$ points within this circle. That includes:

- The origin $(0,0)$
- $4\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor$ points $(0,\pm n)$ and $(\pm n,0)$ for $0<n\leq \sqrt{N}$
- $4\lfloor\sqrt{N/2}\rfloor$ points $(\pm m,\pm m)$ for $0<m\leq\sqrt{N/2}$
- $8M$ points $(\pm a,\pm b)$ and $(\pm b,\pm a)$.

So I estimate $$M={\pi N-1-4\sqrt{N}-4\sqrt{N/2} \over 8}$$ solutions.

**EDIT**: This is called the [Gauss Circle Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem) on Wikipedia, where $r^2$ is used instead of $N$.

Comment: Nice asymptotic solution.

Comment: Beginning with 325 there are also some triplets that you must consider (1,18), (6,17) and (10,15). The triplets generate 3 pairs. Perhaps quadruples etc. as well?

Answer (score 0):

The following approach gives you a possible way to work on the $F(N)$, but doesn't provide a closed formula. Consider the formal power series
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n^2}.$$
Then your number $F(N)$ is given by the sum of the coefficients of $x^k$ for $k\le N$ in $f(x)^2$. Notice that the series can be expressed by means of the [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function): [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20for%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity%20of%20x%5E%28n%5E2%29)